# Loop over a List getting an increasing number of elements each time

Tags: scala, collections

Let's say I have a list that looks like

```
{A, B, C, D, E}
```

And I want to loop over this list, getting an increasing number of elements each time, so each iteration would look like:

```
Iteration 1: {A}  
Iteration 2: {A, B}
Iteration 3: {A, B, C}  
Iteration 4: {A, B, C, D}
Iteration 5: {A, B, C, D, E}
```

Currently I am accomplishing this with:

```
(1 to list.size).foreach( n => {
  val elements = list.take(n)
  // Do something with elements
})
```

But that feels messy. Is there a more 'scala' way of accomplishing this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `list.inits` :

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4,5).inits.foreach(println)
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
List(1, 2, 3, 4)
List(1, 2, 3)
List(1, 2)
List(1)
List()
```

To get your desired out put you would need to create a list from the iterator, reverse it and take the tail to omit the empty list:

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4,5).inits.toList.reverse.tail.foreach(println)
List(1)
List(1, 2)
List(1, 2, 3)
List(1, 2, 3, 4)
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foldLeft` with a linked list to accumulate the elements.

However, this will reverse the order, so you'll need to call the `.reverse` function if you really care about the order, which wouldn't be efficient.

```
list.foldLeft(Nil : List[String]){(l, n) => {
  val elements = n :: l
  println(elements)
  elements
}}
```

Output:

```
List(A)
List(B, A)
List(C, B, A)
List(D, C, B, A)
List(E, D, C, B, A)
```

Here's a version that preserves order but uses a `ListBuffer`, which isn't great

```
val elems = ListBuffer[String]()
list.foreach{ s => 
  elems += s
  println(elems)
}
```

The same, but with a fold

```
list.foldLeft(ListBuffer[String]()){(elems, s) => 
  elems += s
  println(elems)
  elems
}
```

Output:

```
ListBuffer(A)
ListBuffer(A, B)
ListBuffer(A, B, C)
ListBuffer(A, B, C, D)
ListBuffer(A, B, C, D, E)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive version. You will need to reverse the list first.

```
@tailrec
def doIt(l: List[Int], acc: List[List[Int]] = Nil): List[List[Int]] = l match {
  case Nil => acc
  case h :: t => doIt(t, List(h) :: acc.map(l => h :: l))
}


doIt(List(1,2,3).reverse).foreach(println)

// output
List(1)
List(1, 2)
List(1, 2, 3)
```